# use all classes in a namespace

Tags: php, namespaces

I've got a namespace named `Foo`. There are various classes inside that namespace, let say `Bar` and `Baz`.

In some other file, I would like to use the `Foo` namespace and by that gain access to all of it's classes without prefixing them with the `\Foo\ClassName`.

What I've tried to do was at the top of the script:

```
use Foo;
```

And then simply do something like:

```
$bar = new Bar;
```

However, when I try that, I get an error:  `The use statement with non-compound name 'Foo' has no effect`, eventually leading to that I have to specify every class I want to use beforehand. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP's [`use` keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) doesn't work like C++'s `using namespace;` in the sense that you can't include an entire namespace. You can alias it or include each class.

If you want to do `new Bar;`, you'll have to do something like this:

```
use Foo\Bar;
```

You'd have to do this for each class you need in the Foo namespace. As far as i know there is no workaround.

Comment: Do you have a solution around this? I was thinking of include( "models.viewmodels.php" ) which inside would have a list of all the use namespaces

Comment: One thing I notice is that I have to declare namespace on every php class in order to implement phpunit.